# twitter4J i dont know if i need acount

Tags: android, twitter4j

i want implement twitter4j on my app..

I've seen that in all the tutorials you need to have an account on twitter, but also see that in the tutorial send a tweet and see your profile.

What I want is to find tweets by hashtag and list them.

Need acount??

Sorry by my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Signup for an account at [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/).

Then, create an application. You will get a bunch of information including four unique fields:

> Consumer key
>   Consumer secret
>   Access token
>   Access token secret

You will need this unique information to download the tweets. There are a bunch of different ways to do it, depending on operating system, number of tweets needed and what you want to do with them (i.e. sentiment mining, count of retweets etc).

Google is your friend here and can give you hundreds of examples.